# Using and Calling a Specific Commit for a ngx-chess-board Package and Importing it to an Angular module for use Typescript

Tags: typescript, git, import, package, angular11

I had angular ngx-chess-board working but now when I try to run it with angular 11, I get the version incompatible error. The ngx-chess-board supports version of cdk 10 or 13 but I am using 11. I have tried all versions of ngx-chess-board but cannot get a cannot get any version to work with my cdk version.

It looks like ngx-chess-board does not have a version compatible with angular 11.x.. (at least not on their repo's tags).

I want to use [this commit](https://github.com/grzegorz103/ngx-chess-board/commit/e010df373a049af85589106742341f5413a5d782) from ngx-chess-board, as it seems to be compatible with angular 11.
I managed to successfully add it to my package.json but instead of ngx-xhess-board, the package name is ngx:

```
"ngx": "github:grzegorz103/ngx-chess-board#e010df3"
"@angular/cdk": "^11.0.6",
"@angular/cli": "^11.2.19",
"@angular/common": "^11.0.6",
"@angular/compiler": "^11.0.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
```

The issue I am having now is that to get it running before, I had to import the NgxChessBoardModule into my app.module folder as:

```
NgxChessBoardModule.forRoot()
```

but now that the package name is ngx, I see under node modules, the files are coming as ngx and if I use `NgxChessBoardModule.forRoot()`, it cannot be found. Also, if I try importing NGx or ngxModule into the module, as that is the package name, It still doesnt work. Can anyone help me get this working with angular cli version 11?